# Xpath in for loop using Java

Tags: java, selenium, for-loop, xpath

Currently, my code looks like this:

```
for(int k=1; k<4; k++){
    String  elem1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/ul[1]/li[6]/div/ul/li/div/a[k]" + k)).getAttribute("innerHTML");
    //String  elem2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/ul[1]/li[6]/div/ul/li/div/a[2]")).getAttribute("innerHTML");
    //String  elem3 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/ul[1]/li[6]/div/ul/li/div/a[3]")).getAttribute("innerHTML");

    System.out.println(elem1);
    //System.out.println(elem2);
    //System.out.println(elem3);

    Thread.sleep(3000);
    double value = Double.parseDouble(elem1);
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

As you can see in the `String elem1` line, I try to pass the value `k` into XPath, but it doesn't work. How can I do that? I need to increase the value of `k` because as you can see in the commented lines it goes: 1-2-3-4...-78...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the variable `k` in the exact place you want its value:

```
By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div‌​[2]/ul[1]/li[6]/div/ul/li/div/a[" + k + "]")
```